# value % is not a member of scala.xml.NodeSeq

Tags: scala, lift

I'm trying to work through some [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) examples using [CSS Selector Transforms](http://stable.simply.liftweb.net/#sec%3aCSS-Selector-TransformsExampleName).  I'm attempting this sort of transformation:

> - NodeSeq => NodeSeq — a function that transforms the node (yes, it can be a CssBindFunc): `"#name" #> ((n: NodeSeq) => n % ("class" -> "dog")) // <span id="name"/> -> <span id="name" class="dog"/>`

It's the `%` that's giving me trouble right now.  When I try to write code like this, I get the error `value % is not a member of scala.xml.NodeSeq`.  Is there an import or something that I'm missing?

Here's my snippet:

```
import scala.xml._
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._

import model.User

class Users {
  def show = {
    ".userName" #> "name replaced" &
    ".userEmail" #> "email replaced" &
    ".changePassword" #> ((n: NodeSeq) => n % ("href" -> "changePassword"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `Elem` contains the `%` method.  `NodeSeq` is not an `Elem`, but a collection of `Node`s, which may or may not be `Elem`s.  And I'm not sure if Lift's helpers include implicits to create `MetaData`, but if not, you'd need something like

```
myNodeSeq map {
  case e: Elem => e % new UnprefixedAttribute("href","changePassword",xml.Null)
  case x => x
}
```

to cover the generic case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do what you want. It's pretty much equivalent but it doesn't throw any error.

```
import scala.xml._
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._
scala> val res1 = "#name" #> ((n:NodeSeq) => ("* [class]" #> "dog")(n))
res1: net.liftweb.util.CssSel = CssBind(Full(#name), Full(IdSelector(name,Empty)))
scala> res1(<span id="name"/>)
res2: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<span id="name" class="dog"></span>)
```